# JAVA broken while loop

Tags: java

How can I make a program that prompts the user to enter number of rows and columns and output figure resembling hollow rectangle (using "*") formed from these rows and columns using while loops?

```
   Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns: ");

    int row = stdin.nextInt();
    int column = stdin.nextInt();

    int m = 1;

    while(m <= column)
    {
        while(m <= row)
        {
            System.out.println("*\t");
        }
        System.out.print("*");
        m++;
    }
```

Comment: You did it already.  What is your question now ?

Comment: Your innerloop will run forever as long as `row > 1`. Don't use the same variable in the inner loop as the outer one.

Comment: @CollinD I don't understand how my inner loop will run forever

Comment: `m` will always be `<= row` in that inner loop since you are not incrementing in the inner loop. Try using a different variable for the inner loop, and consider a `for` loop instead. Good luck!

Comment: @CollinD Oh ok, great! Also, how can I format this so it always looks like a rectangle?

Comment: Get rid of the tabs and make use of `out.print` rather than `out.println`. Use `out.println` only to create newlines when appropriate. Also some logic to print the first vs last rows will be required. Since the first rows need `col` asterisks, and the other rows need 2 asterisks and `cols-2` spaces.

Comment: Wouldn't each row have to be on a new line? Should I use '\n' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike you Have to use diffrent variables for difflent loop control.

create an "n" and it should work

```
Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of rows and columns: ");

int row = stdin.nextInt();
int column = stdin.nextInt();

int m = 1;
int n = 1;

while(m <= column)
{
    while(n <= row)
    {
        System.out.println("*\t");
        n++;
    }
    System.out.print("*");
    m++;
}
```

Comment: Great thank you ! Now how can I get the print statement for m to show at the top too?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say: get the print statement for m?
I suposed is just to System.out.print(m) or  System.out.print(n)

Comment: My apologies I meant how the last line prints how many symbols are in the column how do I do the same for the first line before I start printing the rows.. so that it looks like a rectangle

Comment: prints only the first line, first collumns and last lines and last columns.

like this

`
if(n == 1 || n == row)  System.out.println("*\t");
if(m == 1 || m == column)  System.out.print("*");
`